# Angular resolver not working with Ionic v4 tabs template

Tags: angular, ionic4, resolver

Using the Ionic v4 tabs template and angular 7.0, I'm attempting to use a resolver to load data for a page before the page renders. In **app-routing.module.ts** below, the resolver *does* work for the 'login' path, but not for the '' path.

So, for example, if I visit my app's base page (i.e. http://localhost:8101), then the TabsPageModule is loaded, and I'm then redirected to '/tabs/(home:home)'. Once that page loads, the TestResolverService data should be available via ActivatedRoute, but it's not.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TestResolverService } from './resolvers/test- 
resolver.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
      path: '',
      resolve: {
          message: TestResolverService
      },
      loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule'
  },
  {
      path: 'login',
      resolve: {
          message: TestResolverService
      },
      loadChildren: './pages/login/login.module#LoginPageModule'
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [TestResolverService]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**tabs.router.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/(home:home)',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        outlet: 'home',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/(home:home)',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

So, my question is, how can I make the resolver data (TestResolverService) available on the page to which the user is being redirected (from '' to '/tabs/(home:home)')?

**Update**
I spent some more time on this and realized that any values passed through the resolver don't survive through the route redirect. So in this case, TestResolverService was available on the login page (no redirect), but not at the root page ('') since that leads to a redirect to '/tabs/(home:home)'.

A solution is to instead store data in an Event or BehaviorSubject.

Comment: share the code of `TestResolverService` and component codes.

Comment: @SunilSingh shared. It's extremely simple just for the sake of testing.